# Websocket api with serverless framework (BlitzJs)?

Tags: javascript, websocket, notifications, serverless, polling

I am using a serverless framework [Blitz.js](https://blitzjs.com) for my app. However, now I want to implement a notification system so the user is notified of any updates. As Blitz.js is serverless, I am not sure how to proceed.

Apologies for the open-ended question, however, I wondered if there is a way/ guide to implement Web-Socket or some kind of polling to inform users?

Secondly, how would one integrate a backend server with a serverless framework like Blitz.

**Update: (sharing my thoughts)**

The way I see it is that the system would work something like the following. The serverless communication between front-end & serverless would continue as is, now the backend server (if really needed for notification/ polling), would communicate with serverless & forward that on to front-end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets are a way for browser-resident code to establish a persistent connection to, well, a server. So you're doing something slightly strange and certainly pioneering trying to use it with a serverless framework.

But, WebSocket connections *are* http (or https) connections. So if your serverless instance endures until all connections are closed, you can conceivably have a connection between your user's browser and your serverless instance.  If you can get your hands on the `server` object in your blitz server-side code you can use [npm ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) to set up a WebSocket listener.

```
const requestIp = require( 'request-ip' )
const ws = require('ws' )

...

const wss = new ws.Server({ server });
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws, request) {
  const url = new URL( request.url, 'wss://example.com', true )
  const path = url.pathname
  const clientIp = requestIp.getClientIp( request )
  console.log ('connected to: %s from %s', path, clientIp) 

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s from %s', message, clientIp);
  })

  ws.on('close', function close (code, reason) {
  console.log ('closed: %s from %s', reason , clientIp) 
  })
 
  ws.send('something');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am aware of Express ws, however, was wondering how to implement it with a serverless.

Answer (score 1):

I just came accross this respository which successfully integrated socketio to blitz.

So it should be possible with custom startup actions.

https://github.com/parkerbedlan/blitz-chat
https://github.com/parkerbedlan/blitz-chat/commit/3aafdb2c115084a44835c79b16c05e59e2d52477

Comment: great find Simon. Yes, I noticed people have been able to integrate custom servers to enable this func.